# MonoTouch - Refresh TableView

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, tableview

I am writing a news application for iOS using MonoTouch. The data comes via an OData web sevice.

I have a singleton class called NewsFactory which is responsible for querying the OData feed. Now in the ViewDidLoad method I am retrieving the list of news articles and binding it to the table view.

However - I am not sure how to refresh this every time the app is launched. I don't care much for "pull to refresh". All I want to make sure is that every time the app is launched (from scratch or activated again) that the call to the web service is made to make sure I show the latest info.

In addition, I want to cover for the scenario where the network connectivity is lost when the app is launched and I notify the user. The use closes the app (suspend) and let's say the network connectivity returns - If the user opens the app again, I would like to make sure that I show the latest news articles.

I am building the view hierarchy programmatically. I have navigation controllers and a tab bar controller with 5 tabs.I am targeting iOS 5.

I tried playing with OnActivated and ViewWillAppear and they don't do exactly what I need to do. This is a very common need for any iOS app so there must be a solution - I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to think, in general, if you call a method that loads from one source (let's say a text file that has data in it), then you change up the source (change text data), but call the same method when the class is loaded, then the new data will appear when the new class is loaded.

Like for example:

```
- (void) loadView {
    NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    textView.text = testString;
}
```

This example shows the setting of text in a file to a UITextView instance. If you load it the first time and the file contained the contents of "Hi", then the textView will say hi. If you change it, then call the same method, then it will show your changed text the second time you load the app.

The point is that if you change data, then call the same method, then you'll see a difference. Unless you're working with a database.

I'd give you a better example if you provide sample code.

EDIT: Not sure if your custom class comes with this function, but it is included in the regular UITableView class:

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

You can call that after your array changes internally.